# Error deploying Rails app to Heroku: simple_form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, simple-form

I have troubles deploying my RoR-app to Heroku. I've changed the database to postgresql, so thats ok. But I get an error with the simple_form gem. I've tried many different approaches available on the net, but no go..

Here's the error message:

```
rake aborted!
   NameError: uninitialized constant SimpleForm
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/config/initializers/simple_form.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /tmp/build_1b6d5373d9f274355d732fd1b0235bfb/gauteremen-workout_log-965e78a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

!
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Here's the new error message, after adding require 'simple_form' in the simple_form.rb

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- simple_form
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/config/initializers/simple_form.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /tmp/build_ed1c1754ca789044f8c2eb91cebaac26/gauteremen-workout_log-cb80141/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

!
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Comment: try using latest version of `simple_form`. which version you are using currently?

Comment: I hope I am using the latest version, 3.1.0. Checked rubygems for the latest.

Comment: can you look into `simple_form.rb`, and add `require simple_form`

Comment: Yep, did that now. Then theres a new error, "cannot find file: simple_form" - no such file or directory. Hmm, so strange..:/ also added "require 'rails'" in the simple_form gem.

Comment: The confusing thing is that it works well on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the problem was. I had placed gems used in the application under development and test in the Gemfile. This resulted in that the Gems were not included in the deployment. I got the same error for bootstrap, so next time I will be sure to add gems outside the dev and test clause.

Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not pushed your updated Gemfile and Gemfile.lock on heroku.

Comment: Hmm, yep. Did a bundle install now, just to be sure that all dependencies were ok. And it was. Checked git, and no changes to the files. The only commit and push that had a change was when i added require 'simple_form' and require 'rails' in the simple_form gem. I can post the new error message, give me a sec

Comment: Do you have rails_12factor gem (https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) in your Gemfile.